# How to convert an ASCII HEX character to it's value (0-15)?

Tags: ascii, hex

I am writing a string parser and the thought occurred to me that there might be some really interesting ways to convert an ASCII hexadecimal character `[0-9A-Fa-f]` to it's numeric value.

What are the quickest, shortest, most elegant or most obscure ways to convert `[0-9A-Fa-f]` to it's value between `0` and `15`?

Assume, if you like, that the character is a valid hex character.

I have no chance so I'll have a go at the most boring.

```
( c <= '9' ) ? ( c - '0' ) : ( (c | '\x60') - 'a' + 10 )
```

Comment: any particular language?

Comment: I'm playing with C, but feel free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(c&15)+(c>>6)*9`

In response to "How does it work", it throws away enough bits so that the numbers map to [0:9] and the letters map to [1:6], then adds 9 for the letters. The `c>>6` is a stand-in for `if (c >= 64) ...`.

Comment: The first part, c&15, will give you 0-9 for the digits ( they're 0x30 to 0x39, & 0x0F clears the top 4 digits => 0x00-0x09 ). 
For the letters A-F, you'll get 1-6 (A is 0x41, F is 0x46, & 0x0F, etc )
Now for the letters you want 10-15, not 1-6, so you need to add 9, but only for letters.
Well, digits are 0011xxxx, letters (A-F) are 0100xxxx, shift that right 6 times and you get 00 for the digits, 01 for the letters. Multiply that by 9, the result becomes 0 in the case of digits, 9 for letters. now add that to the first part and you're set.

Comment: +1 , its nice. doesn't work with lowercase letters though, but it can be modified to.

Comment: @David V: I think it does work for upper and lower case. I tested it, and it does work.

Comment: With no comparisons or jumps, this is probably the quickest and smallest. 14 bytes with gcc -O3.

Comment: gcc multiplies by `9` by `(c>>6<<3)+(c>>6)` or `c/64*8 + c/64`

Comment: I stand corrected, lowercase chars are 0110xxxx which still gives 1 when shifted right 6 times. I wrote too fast.

Comment: Very nice! It does indeed work for both upper and lower case - tested in C.

Comment: Nice! But is there also a nice way to ensure the input character is in the right range? Something shorter than ('0'<=c && c<= '9') || ('A' <= c && ... ) || ...

Comment: @calandoa: I think that would break the bank as far as bit-twiddling goes, since the exact character ranges don't hit nice power-of-two boundaries. You can nevertheless remove branching from the test by using bit-wise instead of logical operators — `if (('0'<=c)&(c<='9)|('A'<=c)&(c<='F')|('a'<=c)&(c<='f')) ...` — though I have no idea whether this buys you anything.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to look for it in a string:

```
int n = "0123456789ABCDEF".IndexOf(Char.ToUpper(c));
```

Another way is to convert it as a digit, and then check if it's a character:

```
int n = Char.ToUpper(c) - '0';
if (n > 9) n -= 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private byte[] HexStringToBytes( string hexString )
{
    byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexString);
    byte[] ret = new byte[bytes.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 2)
    {
       byte hi = (byte)(((bytes[i] & 0x40) == 0) ? bytes[i] & 0x0F : bytes[i] & 0x0F + 9);
       byte lo = (byte)(((bytes[i+1] & 0x40) == 0) ? bytes[i+1] & 0x0F : bytes[i+1] & 0x0F + 9);
       ret[i / 2] = (byte)((hi << 4) | lo);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved with a little explanation of the how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

In `C` you can so something like:

```
if(isdigit(c)) 
  num = c -'0';
else if(c>='a' && c<='f')
  num = 10 + c - 'a';
else if(c>='A' && c<='F')
  num = 10 + c - 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
num = parseInt(hex, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the boring C version (and my C is very rusty, so it's probably wrong as well).

```
char parseIntChar(const char p) {
  char c[2];
  c[0]=p;
  c[1]=0;
  return strtol(c,0,16);
}
```